# RatchetPHP - Client gets disconnected from server right before receiving a message from the server

Tags: php, websocket, composer-php, ratchet, reactphp

So, im trying the Ratchet tutorial (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) and i have a problem:
Everytime the send() method is called on a ConnectionInterface object, this client gets disconnected from server.

Example below:

**SSH terminal**

```
php server1.php
New connection! (54)
New connection! (83)
Connection 83 sending message "test msg" to 1 other connection
Connection 54 has disconnected
```

And i dont even received "test msg" on client 54.

My files:

**server1.php**

```php
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat1;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat1()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

**Chat1.php**

```php
?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat1 implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the error like it.

When I checked the error, **I noticed that on the client side,** when I received the message, I had written things inside the receiving method that would cause the connection to be disconnected from the client side.

This error has nothing to do with the server